# Open external application /Url from salesforce UI

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Account" showHeader="false">

      <apex:iframe src="https://www.youtube.com"/>

</apex:page>
```

I have whitelisted the URL, still it says 'Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.'

From communitites , i can change the clickjack action but I wanted to open any external URL from Salesforce Sales cloud UI like inline account VF page.

Is their is any setting I can turned it off?

Comment: what is the problem, not clear to me.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661182/embed-youtube-video-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-opti

Answer (score 2):

Youtube doesn't allow you to open the home page in an iframe. That's what the SAMEORIGIN error message means. To show a specific video, you have to use that video's "embed" URL.